# Interpreting []::[], []::[]::[] in sml

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, cons

I would like to ask how `[]::[]` and `[]::[]::[]` are interpreted conceptually in SML/NJ.

My thought :

I thought that `[]::[]` would generates error or generates a empty list but in fact it generates `val it = [[]] : 'a list list`.

After I know that `[]::[]` generates `[[]] : 'a list list`, I thought that `[]::[]::[]` would generate `[[[]]] : 'a list list list` but in fact it generates `[[],[]] : 'a list list`

Comment: Do you know how the type of the `::` operator, and its associativity?

Comment: You might want to try `([]::[])::[]` to see how it's different from `[]::([]::[])` (and what you tried)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`::` is right-associative: In `a::b::c::[]` a,b,c must be elements of the same type and

```
a::b::c::[] = a::(b::(c::[]))
            = a::(b::[c])
            = a::[b,c]
            = [a,b,c]
```

This remains true even if a,b,c are []:

```
[]::[]::[]::[] = [[],[],[]]
```